# Wordpress - using query posts on category page

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I'm trying to limit the number of posts that show on a category page. I was doing this with query_posts, like this

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    if (have_posts()){
        query_posts('posts_per_page=6&paged=' . $paged);
```

The problem is that the query_posts seems to keep the site from realizing what category page it's on, so it shows posts from all categories. Is there a way to fix this? It seems like there should be a way to force WordPress to "get the category" after the query_posts so that it realizes what category it's on and will then display only the relevant posts?

------ Editing to show code when using WP_query ----

```
echo '<h4>Latest Resources</h4>'."\n";
    global $post;

    if (have_posts()){
    $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1; 
    $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
                 'post_type' => 'post', 
                 'paged' => $paged,
                 'posts_per_page' => 6));   
        while($the_query->have_posts()) { 
        $the_query->the_post(); 
            if($post->post_type == 'page') continue;
            setup_postdata($post);
            $categories = get_the_category();
                echo '<div class="listing">';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do not user `query_posts` its no good use `WP_Query` instead like so ie:

**EDITED**

```
$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1; 
    $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'category_name' => 'slug of your category here',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 2) 
);
```

more on pagination and `WP_Query` [**here**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters).

**ADDITIONAL INFO**

```
//usage of the $the_query
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
//pagination
get_next_posts_link(Older', $the_query->max_num_pages);
get_previous_posts_link( Newer', $the_query->max_num_pages);
```

Comment: That seemed perfect, but if I use your code as is, I get no listings, and if I change post_type to post,it shows posts from outside the category again

Comment: I've edited my original post to show the code w/ the WP_Query, in case you can see anything I'm doing wrong.

Comment: sorry add `'category_name' => 'slug of your category here'` check my edits above use the slug not the name though

Comment: Part of the problem is that I'm making these edits to the entire category template, so I need this to work for every category. I tried doing 

global $wp_query;
$cat_ID = get_query_var('cat');

and then put
'category_name' => $cat_ID,

but that didn't work.

Comment: try instead of category_name try `'cat'=>$cat_ID`

Comment: That fixed it, thanks! Although I did notice the wp_pagenavi plugin I was using at the bottom now isn't showing, would this do anything to remove it?

Comment: I realize that might be a separate issue, I'm just curious if you know.

Comment: it might since this is paginating with the plugin, what do need the plugin for?

Comment: I'm following a design that was created by someone else, and it wants page numbers at the bottom of the posts instead of the newer/older links. I did also try the code you gave for the older/newer links, and that doesn't show either.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25808/discussion-between-david-chase-and-molly-campbell)